# Foundation 5 SCSS Compilation via scssPHP

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I've been using lessPHP to compile bootstrap less files into final CSS files for quite some time and got interested in Zurb's Foundation. Having only PHP knowledge I've tried compiling the SCSS into CSS like so using scssPHP:

Please note that I used this approach and everything seems to be working fine when using lessPHP with bootstrap's less files.

```
    require_once("scssPHP/scss.inc.php");
    $scss = new scssc;
    return $scss->compile($foo);
```

$foo contains the contents from the main foundation scss file as well as imports for the rest of the .scss files.

When compiling, I get the following response:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'expecting color: failed at `$bg-lightness: lightness($bg);
` /[foundation folder]/scss/_alert-boxes.scss on line 62' in /[scssphp folder]/scss.inc.php:3899
Stack trace:
#0 /[scssphp folder]/scss.inc.php(2364): scss_parser-&gt;throwParseError('expecting color', 2029)
#1 /[scssphp folder]/scss.inc.php(1701): scssc-&gt;throwError('expecting color')
#2 /[scssphp folder]/scss.inc.php(2035): scssc-&gt;assertColor(Array)
#3 [internal function]: scssc-&gt;lib_lightness(Array, Object(scssc))
#4 /[scssphp folder]/scss.inc.php(1588): call_user_func(Array, Array, Object(scssc))
#5 /[scssphp folder]/scss.inc.php(945): scssc-&gt;callBuiltin('lightness', Array, NULL)
#6 /[scssphp folder]/scss.inc.php(591): scssc-&gt;reduce(Array)
#7 /[scssphp folder]/scss.inc.php(723): scssc-&gt;compi in <b>[scssphp folder]/scss.inc.php</b> on line <b>3899</b><br />
```

This is the part in _alert-boxes.scss where the error is encountered for the first time and seems to happen right through the Foundation 5 scss whenever mixins are called even if I remove this to check.

```
@mixin alert-style($bg:$primary-color) {
// This find the lightness percentage of the background color.
$bg-lightness: lightness($bg);
// We control which background color and border come through.
background-color: $bg;
border-color: darken($bg, $alert-function-factor);
// We control the text color for you based on the background color.
@if $bg-lightness > 70% { color: $alert-font-color-alt; }
@else { color: $alert-font-color; }
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem is here or if there's any other method/script I can use to compile the scss into css? Thanks!

Comment: I've resolved the problem by replacing scss.inc.php with the following fix located [here](https://github.com/timonbaetz/scssphp/blob/8e9ad859b8648d972c1b39bde0ad629bfb1b8eaa/scss.inc.php)

Comment: that fix has been pulled into the official repository

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in scssPHP so upgrading to the latest version (0.0.9 at time of writing) will solve this issue.